# Boost.Asio, tcp::iostream, and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

**tl;dr**

How do I make a `tcp::iostream` based server, as in the code below, accept multiple connections in separate threads?

---

I am trying my hand at implementing a server / client interface for a preexisting library using Boost.Asio, feeling my way along the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html). (Yes, pre-C++11. Bear with me.)

**Rationale for going with tcp::iostream.**

Due to circumstances, the whole server process is optional; i.e. when the client is invoked with `port = 0`, it passes the request to a local `Handler` instance. In every other case, it connects with the server hopefully listening at that port number, and the server passes the request to a `Handler` instance of the server process.

(This is all strictly 127.0.0.1. The server exists because there is significant shared state between multiple `Handler` instances, so if all users would send their requests to one server running on the machine, it would be much easier on memory and start-up times. The "local", `port = 0` option exists because that way I can get away with only one client executable for both server-based and local use.)

Anyway. There is [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html), which makes things really easy:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port_ );
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor( io_service, endpoint );

for (;;)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    acceptor.accept( *stream.rdbuf(), ec );
    if ( ! ec )
    {
        Handler( stream, stream ).run(); // <---- This is the "why"
    }
    else
    {
        throw ec.message();
    }
    stream.close();
}
```

You see where this is going. The `Handler` class takes one input stream and one output stream. Instead of passing `tcp::iostream`, I could pass `std::cin` / `std::cout`, or some `std::fstream` pointing to a request file and a log file. This works very nicely for me.

**The big "but"**

The problem is that the above code is strictly single-threaded. As the job done by `Handler` takes *significant* time (minutes), I need more than one worker thread.

And all the examples and tutorials on "how to make Boost.Asio multithreaded" -- e.g. the HTTP examples [server2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server2/server.cpp) (using a pool of individual `io_service` objects) and [server3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server3/server.cpp) (using several threads each calling `io_service::run()`) -- are going a completely different way (`acceptor::async_accept()` working on a `tcp::socket` object contained in a separate `connection` object).

Blame it on either my confusion about the overall architecture of Boost.Asio, or a lacking documentation, but I cannot figure out how to combine the two approaches, i.e. have multiple worker threads, each handling its connection as a `tcp::iostream`. There seems to be no way to retrieve a `tcp::socket` from `tcp::iostream`, nor a way to feed one to it, at which point I am a bit stumped.

Comment: Did you come across a certain tutorial, I think on gamedev? I can dig it out for you, but I used it a few years ago to do the io_service / tcp thing. From what I recall, the io_service/run thing is a way to make a bunch of threads, which can do whatever you like, but are meant to be used with asio's various sockets and such.

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio?pg=11 Found it, happened to be in my favourites

Comment: @Carlos how does adding 1 more tutorial help?

Comment: @DevSolar, how about starting a thread for each handler and just passing the iostream or socket into it?

Comment: @sehe: But I would need a *separate* `tcp::iostream` for each `Handler`, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Comment: @sehe: There is some communication disconnect here. I know how I could spawn a couple of `io_service` objects (as the Boost examples showcase), but I don't know how to get from there to `tcp::iostream` (as its [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_iostream/basic_socket_iostream/overload2.html) wants *resolver query* parameters)...?!? And I can't just spawn threads and have each one's `tcp::iostream` listen to the same port, or can I? (Address already in use...)

Comment: @sehe it's nice to know if he's already tried one path.

Comment: Why combine the two approaches at all? Why not just use the traditional asio approach which sounds like it should be optimal for your use case?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Ref. "Rationale for going with `tcp::iostream`"...? I very much like the fact that I can have *one* `Handler` class that does the processing regardless of whether it's file-based, `cin` / `cout`, or over the network. Also, the chaining of `async_*()` calls and callbacks (which I assume you mean by "the traditional asio approach") feels cumbersome.

Comment: @DevSolar You can use stackful coroutines then. But actually now that I think about it, it sounds like you may just want to dispatch the long-running work to a separate pool of threads.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Using coroutines  would still not give me a transparent `std::iostream` interface. I don't see your point. I could have picked a dozen other ways, but `tcp::iostream` was what I wanted because I *need* `Handler` to be able to do file-based work as well. You could also ask why I don't use C++11 -- because I have to support SLES 11 with it's pre-C++11 compiler. Or why I limit myself to 127.0.0.1 -- because this is strictly back-end stuff, as the front end (which does user authorization, encryption, billing etc.) already exist and the service must not be available from off-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm subtly missing the question here. It doesn't seen related to Asio:

**<kbd>[Live C++03 On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f19771340930145)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/basic_socket_iostream.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Handler {
    std::istream& is;
    std::ostream& os;

    Handler(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os) : is(is), os(os){}
    void run() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::string line;

        while (getline(is, line)) {
            std::reverse(line.begin(), line.end());
            os << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

struct SocketRequest : boost::enable_shared_from_this<SocketRequest> {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

    void start() {
        boost::async(boost::launch::async, boost::bind(&SocketRequest::do_run, shared_from_this()));
    }

  private:
    void do_run() {
        return Handler(stream, stream).run();
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    unsigned short port_ = 6767;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port_);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);

    for (;;)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<SocketRequest> req = boost::make_shared<SocketRequest>();

        acceptor.accept(*req->stream.rdbuf());
        req->start();
    }
}
```

For sample clients:

```
(for req in HELLO BYE; do sleep 1; netcat 127.0.0.1 6767 <<< "$req"; done)&
```

Prints

```
void Handler::run():16
OLLEH
void Handler::run():16
EYB
```

Comment: I used c++11 thread for speed here, obviously you'd use Boost Thread for c++03 compatibilty

Comment: I am sorry to ask this of you, but could you turn this into C++03 / Boost.Thread-using code? Looking at the (also unfamiliar) `std::future` parts interspersed with the Boost.Asio code which I am struggling to grasp is somewhat compounding my frustration about being too dense to "get" it.

Comment: Or, to put it differently -- all the multithreading examples from the Boost docs are about making multiple calls to `io_service::run()`. Your example does not call `io_service::run()` even *once*. I see the code well enough, but I fail to grasp the concept(s) behind it. :-(

Comment: Hah - Boost Future and Boost Move in C++03 are... complicated. I don't know how to use [BOOST_MOVE_RET](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/BOOST_MOVE_RET.html) yet, but in your case you might not care about the return: here's a start http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c2337e92446511d

Comment: `io_service::run()` is for async use

Comment: Indeed, there is no return of `Handler::run()` in my case, so you can do away with that. I don't see where I am supposed to spawn threads, i.e. what is shared (the acceptor?) and what isn't. Sorry but I cannot phrase the question any better. I *know* I'll be slapping my forehead once the lightbulb switches on...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159610/discussion-between-sehe-and-devsolar).

Comment: And if you wholly don't care how many requests (ie. threads) are running at a given time and also don't care about orderly shutdown, you can use the naive approach with detached threads each time: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b79c4b08c1dd24c7

Comment: Fixing link: Here's a different approach when you want to explicitly control the number of threads. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa30918f9acc3ff - in this case we use `io_service` for an extra purpose: it serves as a task-queue (see post)